# Cannot compile some simple D code

Tags: d

I'm compiling some simple code:

```
import std.c.time;
.
.
.
timespec zero;
nanosleep(&zero, null);
.
.
.
```

What I get is:

```
Error: undefined identifier timespec
Error: undefined identifier nanosleep
```

`std.c.time` is merely a shortcut to C's `time.h`.
If I call other functions defined in `time.h`, say `clock()`, it's Ok.
If I write analogous code in C (with `nanosleep()`), it's Ok.
In `time.h` I see that `timespec` and `nanosleep` declarations are put under some `#ifdef`, possibly it has something to do with my problem ?

How can I get it to compile ?

My working environment is:
dmd v2.059
Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Why not using `std.datetime`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As nightcracker right pointed out, `nanosleep()` does not belong to C99 standard, however it belongs to POSIX, consequently, all that was needed is `import core.sys.posix.time;`.
One general conclusion, search D libraries / interfaces.

Answer (score 5):

`timespec` and `nanosleep` is mentioned exactly 0 times in the C99 standard. It's not part of standard C, can not be found in a standard `time.h` file and thus can not be found in `std.c.time`.

Comment: Yeah yeah ... As a matter of fact, I got it the moment I posted this question. The right place to look is, of course, not time.h, rather time.di in D runtime.

Comment: @segfault If this answers your question, then don't forget to accept it. Right now, your question is listed as unanswered, because you haven't accepted an answer yet.